# NullPointerException in kotlin and anko

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, kotlin, anko, kotlin-null-safety

I'm a beginner at both **Kotlin** and **Anko**.I have learned that **Kotlin** is null safe, but the code below would cause `NullPointerException`, I don't know why, can someone explain it to me?

```
intent.extras["Key"]?.toString()

textView(intent.extras["Key"]?.toString() ?: "Nothing") 
.lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a lot to comment on.. but for start you must first check if the intent is passed to you otherwise it's going to be null so one **NPE** here, and also I think you should check if `TextView` is null (though I don't use Anko)..

For example:

```
intent?.extras["Key"]?.toString()?:"empty"
```

or

```
intent?.extras?.get("key")?.toString()?:"empty"
```

Please provide your exception log for further investigation (^^)
Cheers

Comment: It seems you should check if extras is null or notintent.extras?.get("key")?.toString()?:"empty"

Comment: It seems I should check if extras is null first. Then I changed my code to :

intent.extras?.get("key")?.toString()?:"empty"

It works fine!

This line : intent.extras["Key"] is not null safe!!!

Comment: I know, I mean you should check for intent too.. intent can be null itself let alone the extras..

Answer (score 0):

It seems I should check if extras is null first. Then I changed my code to :

intent.extras?.get("key")?.toString()?:"empty"

It works fine!

This line :  intent.extras["Key"]   is not null safe!!!